# Serialize subset of class

Tags: c#, json, rest, json.net

I won't go into all the things I've tried...

This is approximately what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
public interface IClientDTO {
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
}

public class DTO : IClientDTO {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        DTO dto = new DTO() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", SSN = "111001111" };
        IClientDTO clientDTO = dto;
        string sDTO = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dto);
        string sClientDTO = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(clientDTO);

        Debug.WriteLine(sDTO);
        Debug.WriteLine(sClientDTO);
    }
}
```

I would like my output to look like this...

> {"SSN":"111001111","FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}
>
> {"FirstName":"John","LastName":"Doe"}

I didn't think it would be that difficult, but since the Serializer always determines the type as DTO I always get the SSN value even on the occasions I don't want to.

This is of course just a little test.  Lets say that I have a WebAPI application mocked up something like this.

```
public class AdminController : ApiController {
    public DTO Get() { return new Model().DTO); }
}

public class ClientController : ApiController {
    public IClientDTO Get() { return new Model().DTO); }
}
```

I'd like the Serializer to serialize only those items defined in the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `JsonIgnoreAttribute` to *always* not include SSN.

```
public class DTO : IClientDTO {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}
```

If you want to programatically determine  weather or not to include it, you could create two classes - a base `ClientDTO` with FirstName, LastName, etc. Then a `ClientWithSSN` type, that inherits from `ClientDTO` and contains just SSN. Then, when chosing to return SSN or not, cast to the base type with no ssn or return the actual  `ClientWithSSN` type.

Comment: Thanks for taking time Cam.  I can't use [JsonIgnore] since there are times like when I serialize to the back end store when I want the SSN included.  I had also tried using classes and inheritance, but that doesn't work either.  When you check the type at run-time its still 'ClientWithSSN'.  You can make it work using unrelated classes with a copy constructor or explicit type converter but that sort of defeats the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I like controlling object access through returned interfaces.  Its nice that the compiler controls access and visibility.

However when it comes to serialization the compiler isn't there to referee.  So I think my question is a moot one.  As soon as the Json.net serializer issues...

```
return base.Serializer._contractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());
```

It's pretty much a done deal.
Sure, you can jack with things and poke things, but if you can't do it globally based on type I don't really see the point.  So I'm going with something like this based on Cam's  suggestion.

```
public interface IClientDTO {
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
}

public interface IAdminDTO {
    string FirstName { get; }
    string LastName { get; }
    string SSN { get; }
}

class ClientDTO : IClientDTO {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class AdminDTO : IAdminDTO {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

class Model {
    class DTO {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string SSN { get; set; }
    }
    private DTO dto = new DTO() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe", SSN = "111001111" };
    public IClientDTO ClientDTO { get { return new ClientDTO() { FirstName = dto.FirstName, LastName = dto.LastName }; } }
    public IAdminDTO AdminDTO { get { return new AdminDTO() { SSN = dto.SSN, FirstName = dto.FirstName, LastName = dto.LastName }; } }
}

class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Model model = new Model();
        string sClientDTO = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.ClientDTO);
        string sAdminDTO = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model.AdminDTO);

        Debug.WriteLine(sClientDTO);
        Debug.WriteLine(sAdminDTO);

    }
}
```

Sure it's a little clunky and repetitive, but it still allows me to maintain access through the interfaces and I can let the serializer do its thing unhindered, and I suspect it will be easier to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ContractResolver to handle this:

```
private class IgnoreSSNResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        Debug.Write(type.Name);
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);

        var props = properties.Where((x) => x.PropertyName != "SSN");


        return props.ToList();
    }
}
```

Then when you serialize, you just do this:

```
JsonSerializerSettings sets = new JsonSerializerSettings();
sets.ContractResolver = new IgnoreSSNResolver();

string sClientDTO = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (clientDTO,sets);
```

Comment: Thanks John.  This is close to what I need, but if I serialize DTO through the same configured serializer it removes SSN as well.  This same issue I was having when I tried using custom converters for this.  That is the 'type' parameter passed to CreateProperties() is DTO and not IClientDTO.  If I could determine when the underlying type DTO is being passed through the interface and when it is not I think that would solve the problem.  Maybe my question is more a reflection issue than anything else.

Comment: Perhaps, I'd like it choose the resolver to use.  I have a collection of resolvers and converters already.  I thought that was a 'do the right thing when you encounter this type' mechanism.